# Cannot pair Logitech MX Keys with Xubuntu

Tags: keyboard, xubuntu, bluetooth, logitech

[20.04 - Logitech MX Keys won't pair with Bluetooth](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1270419/20-04-logitech-mx-keys-wont-pair-with-bluetooth)

I already installed the firmware bit that is currently the chosen answer, and passkey still isn't shown or generated in either the terminal or on blueman. Solaar doesn't show any devices, not even the currently paired MX Master Mouse that successfully paired via blueman.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [20.04 - Logitech MX Keys won't pair with Bluetooth](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1270419/20-04-logitech-mx-keys-wont-pair-with-bluetooth)

Answer (score 0):

It seems using `bluetoothctl pair <mac address>` wouldn't show the passkey no matter what. So, instead, I had to do the following:

```
bluetoothctl
[MX Master]# default-agent
[MX Master]# scan on
<Bunch>
<of devices>
<appear>
<here.>
[MX Master]# pair <mac address>
passkey: **######**
```

After entering the passkey and hitting enter it worked finally. Blueman still failed to show a passkey obviously.