# Logitech MX Keys mini is not recognized in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, keyboard, bluetooth, logitech

I just bought a keyboard Logitech MX Keys Mini. I turned it on but it doesn't appear in the bluetooth devices list in Ubuntu 20.04:

[image]

As you can see, I don't see any keyboards. Maybe any driver is missing?

I could pair the keyboard perfectly with my iPad and my Windows computer. What can I do? I already googled but I couldn't find a solution

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I managed to solve this by enabling low energy support for bluetooth.
Run in terminal

```
sudo btmgmt le on
```

and it should display a message

> hci0 Set Low Energy complete, settings: powered connectable discoverable bondable ssp br/edr le

References

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32947807/cannot-connect-to-ble-device-on-raspberry-pi

Comment: After hours of searching, this is the ONLY solution that worked. Thank you! Forgot I had turned off the low energy support because I was trying to pair my QC35 headphones. I'm surprised the MX Keys Mini doesn't work over the USB-C. The main problem I was facing was that the keyboard wasn't showing up when I was searching for Bluetooth devices. I guess that was because bluetooth LE was disabled.

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1390732/806871) by [ybonda](https://askubuntu.com/users/998680/ybonda) worked for me:

> Open your terminal and type the following:
>
> ```
> bluetoothctl
> power off
> power on
> agent KeyboardOnly
> default-agent
> pairable on
> scan on
> pair <mac address>
> ## the passkey will be printed, enter it on your keyboard ##
> trust <mac address>
> connect <mac address>
> quit
> ```