# Ubuntu 22.04 Cant pair logitech MX keys mini

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth, logitech

Took note of
[20.04 - Logitech MX Keys won't pair with Bluetooth](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1270419/20-04-logitech-mx-keys-wont-pair-with-bluetooth)

In my case, however, I don`t event get the PIN displayed.

When using system bluetooth manager if I try to pull the slider ON it immediately reverts to OFF

If I use the `bluetoothctl` it fails for authorization

```
[bluetooth]# pair D8:37:12:F6:B9:A0
Attempting to pair with D8:37:12:F6:B9:A0
[CHG] Device D8:37:12:F6:B9:A0 Connected: yes
Failed to pair: org.bluez.Error.AuthenticationFailed
[CHG] Device D8:37:12:F6:B9:A0 Connected: no
```

Steps I considered:

- Loading firmware from on of the answers. However, my bluetooth adapter is intel, so firmware loading didn`t help me. Apparently everything is OK with the hardware

```
[  171.922737] Bluetooth: hci0: Minimum firmware build 1 week 10 2014
[  171.923024] Bluetooth: hci0: Found device firmware: intel/ibt-17-16-1.sfi
[  173.471226] Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for firmware download to complete
[  173.471765] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware loaded in 1514254 usecs
[  173.490709] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware revision 0.1 build 26 week 11 2020
```

- Settings `agent KeyboradOnly`
- Settings `agent NoInputNoOutput`. It just says the same - authentication failed
- Using `blueman` with no luck. When I try to pair the keyboard it displays "connected" notification, then "disconnected":

```
ypaykov@nbubnt296:~$ blueman-manager 
blueman-manager 00.17.26 WARNING  ManagerDeviceList:341 _monitor_power_levels: Failed to get power levels, probably a LE device.
blueman-manager 00.17.26 ERROR    Manager:213 error_handler:  Authentication Failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/bluez/Base.py", line 78, in callback
    value = proxy.call_finish(result).unpack()
gi.repository.GLib.GError: g-io-error-quark: GDBus.Error:org.bluez.Error.AuthenticationFailed: Authentication Failed (36)
```

- Enabling le power

```
ypaykov@nbubnt296:~$ sudo btmgmt le on
[sudo] password for ypaykov: 
hci0 Set Low Energy complete, settings: powered connectable discoverable bondable ssp br/edr le secure-conn
```

Could anybody point what else can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found some article on Reddit and there was a comment that solved my problem.

The said, to put the keyboard in the pairing mode you need to not just press 1,2, or 3 Device switch key, but also `Esc` and **hold** it for like 4-5 secs

Then the LED on the key will go in and out "super fast". And that's when PIN code started to display on my Ubuntu